# Create a path to image folder using mysql and php

Tags: php, sql, xampp

Basically I have to create a jukebox type chart via mysql and php using xampp.

I've done the basics of setting up the table my referring to mysql database etc. I just dont get how to code the path to the image folder I have created.

My `Image` folder is in `htdocs` under my folder I created called Jukebox.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
     border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "jukebox";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Music";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table>

     <tr>

     <th>Artist</th>
     <th>Title</th>
     <th>Album</th>
     <th>Albumcover</th>
     <th>Play</th>
     </tr>";


// output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

         echo 

         "<tr>

         <td>" . $row["Artist"]. "</td>
         <td>" . $row["Title"]. "</td>
         <td>" . $row["Album"]. "</td>
         <td>" . $row["Albumcover"] 






         . "</td>
         <td>" . $row["Play"] . "</td>

         </tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";



} else {
     echo "0 results";
}



?>  


</body>
</html>
```

[This is what comes up as my online jukebox, and in the Album cover column I want the album art to come up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juUSq.png)

[And this is where my images are, how would i create the path to img folder so the album art comes up?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKXlO.png)

Comment: In which folder you save your Albumcover images?

Comment: Please show your one of that Albumcover data that will help for the answer

Comment: Alright, what do you mean? One of the jpgs? This is for the mp3's yeah?

Comment: No i mean what you store in your albumcover field

Comment: There should be pictures that show whats in the albumcover field, it's the name of the image file, so that it could get read and display the albumcover, but i've figured that out now lol it's just the mp3's now

Comment: ok i get it i am trying for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the image in the "Albumcover" part of your code. If so you can echo out a html line. You can name your images in the "jukebox" folder with the album name. The code will appear as

```
 <td>" . $row["Artist"]. "</td>
 <td>" . $row["Title"]. "</td>
 <td>" . $row["Album"]. "</td>
 <td>" <img src=\"jukebox/".$row["Album"].".png\" >"</td>
```

For that all images will need to be of file type png which is easy to do, just save them normally and add .png at the end. The same album name on your database will need to be the same name given to the file. There are other filetypes you can use such as .jpg.

Comment: I have the album cover images saved in a folder which i want to put into coding so that it can translate as the actual album cover art once displayed in the table. Does that make more sense :/ ? I'm quite confused about how to put it into words. This is an example of what I have to do bluedashed.com/covers I currently only have the database I've made on phpadmin displayed as a table with all the relevant information in them

Comment: I've edited my answer as I think it might be more what you're looking for

Comment: I've changed it again, sorry. I realised you had used " where I was using '. If you had copied it over it wouldn't have worked

Comment: I've edited my post with some images of where I'm at at the moment so maybe things would be a bit clearer, cos it doesn't work and I think I'm being quite vague

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see your problem.
What do you store in "albumcover"?
Let's say you save the relative path to your albumcover.
So you can print out

```
<td><img src="' . $row["Albumcover"] . '"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your mp3 as a tag and open that in a new tab.May be this is you needed.I assume jukebox/mp3/ as your mp3 folder

```
<?php
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 echo 
 "<tr>

 <td>" . $row["Artist"]. "</td>
 <td>" . $row["Title"]. "</td>
 <td>" . $row["Album"]. "</td>
 <td><img src='jukebox/img/" . $row["Albumcover"] ."' alt=".$row["Albumcover"]."></td>
 <td><a href='jukebox/mp3/" . $row["Play"] . "' target='blank'>" . $row["Play"] . "</a>
 </td>

 </tr>";
}
```

Comment: Okay, the audio file now comes up as a hyperlink but it doesnt actually load any music, I've been told that I should try using this coding to allow the music to play but where abouts? 

<audio controls>
  <source src="link/to/mp3file/name.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

Comment: PHP is a server-side script that is used more for data processing and interacting with databases. What you're looking for is a client-side script, so using javascript or flash is the better way to play MP3's. There are plenty of free JS and Flash plugins for you to download or install on the internet.

SoundManager2, http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/ which is more of a development type API, for creating and customizing your own applications.